# Microservices & Business Process Monitoring

Tags: activiti, bpmn, microservices

If we move to a micro services architecture, how can we handle business process management? We are thinking of moving away from our monolith to a micro service based application. One of the challenges we face is monitoring the status of user tasks & jeopardy management. How can we do this if we use micro services?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

activiti is based on it database, all process actions implies an update in it. So you can make a micro service which use the Activiti API (ProcessEngine with the jobExecutor to false) and ask the database to find the usertask's status.

Answer (score 0):

You can view process management as another microservice, which can invoke or be invoked by other microservices.

Check the SpringBoot documentation on the Activi´s user guide on that topic.